# Nothing printed to stdout of a piped process(that takes in input from the pipe)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pipe

## Piping cat and grep

```
int launch_pipe(char **args,int pipe_loc,int argc){
    int pipe_buff_s = PIPE_BUFF_S;
    int status_1,status_2;
    char **arr_out = malloc(pipe_buff_s * sizeof(char *));
    char **arr_in = malloc(pipe_buff_s * sizeof(char *));
    pid_t child_out, child_in, wpid_1,wpid_2;
    
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    
    //closing pipes in the parent process
    
    child_out = fork();
    if(child_out == 0){ //pipe output end
        for(int i = 0; i < pipe_loc; i++){  //args for output child
            arr_out[i] = args[i];
        }
        
        dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);  //duplicating to standard output - 0
        close(fd[0]);   
        close(fd[1]);
        
        if(execvp(arr_out[0],arr_out) == -1){
            perror("error pipe out");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    
    child_in = fork();
    if(child_in == 0){  //pipe input end
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = pipe_loc+1; i < argc ; i++){    //args for input child
            arr_in[j] = args[i];
            j++;
            
            if(j == argc - pipe_loc - 1){
                break;
            }
        }
        arr_in[j] = NULL;
        
        dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);   //duplicating to standard input - 0
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        
        execvp(arr_in[0],arr_in);
        /*if(execvp(arr_in[0],arr_in) == -1){
            perror("error pipe in");
        }else{
            fflush(stdout);
        }*/
    }
    
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    do{
        wpid_1 = waitpid(child_out,&status_1,WUNTRACED); // return status if the child has exited
        wpid_2 = waitpid(child_in,&status_2,WUNTRACED);
    }while(!WIFEXITED(status_1) && WIFSIGNALED(status_1) && !WIFEXITED(status_2) && WIFSIGNALED(status_2));
    
    free(arr_in);
    free(arr_out);
    
    return 1;
}
```

> cat crash.c | grep 'main'

Provided the above prompt and checked for any issues with pipe and they reached the other end just fine.Tried fflush(stdout) but still got nothing onto the screen. I did not touch the grep's output fd, so it should still be mapped to stdout,right?

The arguments were parsed perfectly to my knowledge,any issues with my grep?

Comment: You should post a complete program rather than only a function.

Comment: What's `PIPE_BUFF_S`?

Comment: the command argument arrays `arr_out` and `arr_in` must be terminated with a `NULL` pointer. Here, extra garbage arguments might be passed to `cat` and/or `grep` causing the commands not working as expected

Comment: like you suggested ,I NULL terminated the arrays and also tried the execlp variation and passed the values manually and got the desired output. When i try to access the arr_in[1] that has 'main' string,the whole line does not get executed by the compiler "!: cat crash.c | grep 'main' " was my prompt

Comment: using fflush(stdout) prints arr_in[1] to the screen but still can't figure out for execvp for grep